# SAS: Quoting Problems

Tags: sas, sas-macro, quoting

I am trying to generate a script from within SAS.  Unfortunately, I need to write the line

```
strMSHTA = "mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE>" _
      & "<script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')" _
      & ".GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>"""
```

To write the script to file, I am using the following approach:

```
/* write the script to file */
filename outfile ".\temp.vbs";
data _null_;
  file outfile;
  put 'WScript.Echo "Hello, World!"';
run;

/* run the script */
data _null_;
  call system(".\temp.vbs");
run;

/* housekeeping */
%let rc=%sysfunc(fdelete(outfile));
%symdel rc;
filename outfile clear;
```

Unfortunately, the `put` statement doesn't take kindly to `&`, `'`, and `"`.  I have tried all of the [macro quoting functions](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/67912/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0o0rjikrg6iezn1ltra79iamibr.htm), but cannot get anything to work.  If necessary, I could use the overloaded concatenation operator `+` instead of `&`.  Doing this leaves only an error with the middle line due to the single quotes on `ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')`.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the problem.  Using single quotes instead of double quotes on the outside of your literal strings will eliminate the need to worry about macro triggers like `&` or `%`, but you will still need to double up any literal single quote characters you need to generate.

```
put 
 'strMSHTA = "mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE>" _'
/'      & "<script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject(''Scripting.FileSystemObject'')" _'
/'      & ".GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>"""'
;
```

You could also break your strings literals into multiple string literals and use different outer quotes for each.

```
put 
 'strMSHTA = "mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE>" _'
/'      & "<script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('
 "'Scripting.FileSystemObject'" 
 ')" _'
/'      & ".GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>"""'
;
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was unaware that I could use double-single quotes to prevent the outer single quotes from closing.  I was also unaware that `/` could be used to insert a carriage return.  Do you happen to know where I can find explanations of either of these in the SAS documentation?

Comment: Look at the man page for the PUT statement. Look for the section on line-pointer controls.   Look for the concept page on words in the SAS language.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/68089/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1qge1g4ytqq41n1e8x8s7ugmyst.htm